# How can I find all php class files without strict_types declaration (RegExp / PhpStorm)

Tags: php, regex, phpstorm, regex-negation

I'm trying to add the strict type declaration `declare(strict_types=1);` to all PHP class and trait files under a specific directory.

1. How can I get a list of files without that declaration using Linux terminal?
2. How can I add missing declarations using PhpStorm (inspection, replace in path + regexp)?

Example /src/Foobar.php without declaration:

```
<?php
/**
 * class file
 */
namespace Foo\Bar;

use Other\Foo\Bar;

class Foobar {
  // ..
}
```

Example /src/Foobar.php with declaration:

```
<?php
/**
 * class file
 */
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Foo\Bar;

use Other\Foo\Bar;

class Foobar {
  // ..
}
```

Comments and imports ("use") are optional within a class file.

What I've done:

- Trying to find a PhpStorm inspection that does what I want
- Trying RegularExpressions but didn't find any statement searching for a lack of something within a multi-row context

Comment: Maybe `grep 'declare(strict_types=1);' -vrl .` from the root of your code base.

Comment: @chris85 I checked manpage and as I understood it, it should work theoretically. Practically it fails (showing both files, with and without "declare").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need regex for this - just use built-in "quick fix" for that.

1. Select files/folder(s) where you wish to run such stuff in Project View panel
2. `Code | Run Inspection by Name...`
3. Find `Missing strict type declaration` inspection there (e.g. type `strict` and select it from narrowed list) and run it
4. Confirm the scope (where to run this inspection on)
5. See the results -- you may now apply Quick Fix (many ways -- at least 3 are shown on my screen) -- can be done on per file basis as well as all in one go

### Screenshots:

Finding inspection to run:

[image]

Applying the fix (NOTE: I've run this inspection on single file only that has your sample code as content):

[image]

---

Alternatively -- just enable appropriate inspection (which is disabled by default) and you will be able to add such code via usual <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> (on Windows using Default keymap; or via "light bulb" icon) directly in the code:

**Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | PHP | Type Compatibility | Missing strict type declaration**

[image]

Quick fix menu (`Alt+Enter`)

[image]

Comment: Is that a new feature? I swear I was checking the inspections .. :D Thank you.

Comment: @MonkeyMonkey The inspection itself should be available since 2016.3 (if I'm right it was implemented back in August 2016 -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28318). Possibly it was not covering some aspects .. or was not providing the quick fix intention from the start .. but it [has been around for 4-5 months now](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33790#comment=27-1691460) for sure...